# How to prove Halmos’s Inequality

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, hilbert-spaces, operator-theory, banach-algebras

How to prove Halmos’s Inequality?

If $A$ and $B$ are bounded linear operators on a Hilbert space
such that $A$, or $B$, commutes with $AB-BA$ then $$\|I-(AB- BA)\|\ge 1.$$

I found it from http://www.staff.vu.edu.au/rgmia/monographs/bullen/Dict-Ineq-Supp-Comb.pdf at page 18.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are several proofs and the inequality is given as problem 233 in Halmos's *[A Hilbert Space Problem Book](http://books.google.com/books?id=S57XLkgbf0oC)*. The inequality was originally proved in P.R. Halmos, *[Commutators of Operators, II](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2372409)*, American Journal of Mathematics
Vol. **76**, No. 1 (Jan., 1954), pp. 191–198.

The following very nice proof is given by Philip Maher in *A short commutator proof*, International Journal of Science and Mathematics Education **27** (6) (1996), 934–935. If you have access, you find it online [here](http://dx.doi.org/10.1080/0020739960270617).

Suppose $\|I-(AB-BA)\| \lt 1$. Then $(AB-BA)$ is invertible and as (without loss of generality) $A$ commutes with $(AB-BA)$ by hypothesis, we have that $A$ commutes with $(AB-BA)^{-1}$. Therefore
$$I = (AB-BA)(AB-BA)^{-1} = A[B(AB-BA)^{-1}]  - [B(AB-BA)^{-1}]A$$
and thus $I$ is exhibited as a commutator, and this is well-known to be impossible by a theorem of Wielandt and Wintner; [see e.g. Qiaochu's question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/54397/) for a proof of that fact. Therefore $\|I-(AB-BA)\| \geq 1$.

Note that this proof has nothing to do with bounded operators on a Hilbert space. It works just as well in any Banach algebra.

Comment: comment as above.