# Showing that the inner product space $X$ is a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $X$ be an inner product space. Show that $X$ is a Hilbert space **if and only if** for each continuous linear functional $L$ on $ X$, there exists $z \in X$ such that $$ L(x) = \langle x,z \rangle $$

Here, one part is exactly the [Riesz representation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_representation_theorem). How can I prove the converse result? That is, If for each continuous linear functional $ L$ on $ X$,there exists $ z\in X$ such that $ L(x)=\langle x,z\rangle $ then $ X $ is a Hilbert space.Any Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Suppose $x_n$ is a Cauchy sequence in $X$.
Consider the linear functional $L(x) = \lim_n \langle x, x_n \rangle$.

Comment: How can I turn this into a Cauchy  sequence in $\mathcal C $ or $\mathcal R $? That is the difficulty here.Can you please explain me further?

Comment: You don't "turn this into a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb C$ or $\mathbb R$".  Can you prove $L(x)$ exists, and that $L$ is a bounded linear functional?  If so, take $z$ so that $L(x) = \langle x, z \rangle$.  The limit of the Cauchy sequence $x_n$ is going to be $z$.  Can you estimate $\|x_n - z\|$?

Comment: @ robert,still its difficult for me to organize the answer for this.Can you please help me?

Comment: Which part are you stuck on?

Comment: The basic idea here is to pic a sequence in $ X$ and show that the limit also in $ X $.So how can I prove that $lim_n\langle x,x_n\rangle=\langle x,z\rangle$.How to estimate $ ∥x_n−z∥$?

Comment: Next hint: $\left|\langle x, x_n \rangle - \langle x, x_m \rangle\right| \le \|x \| \|x_n - x_m \|$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael This is an old question but still , what your answer does is show that $x_{n}\rightharpoonup z$  . But as you say, to estimate $||x_{n}-z||$, we do need a Hahn-Banach type of argument . I have posted essentially a "completion" to your answer .

Answer (score 1):

by the hints we know that $\langle x, x_n \rangle$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{K}$. Hence it converges. We know that $L(x) = \langle x, z \rangle \rightarrow \langle x,z \rangle = \lim_n \langle x, x_n \rangle$. By choosing $L(x_n-z)$ we get $x_n = z$. So every Cauchy sequence in $X$ converges so $X$ is a Hilbert space.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the limit $\langle x,x_n \rangle $, converge because

$$ | \langle x,x_n \rangle- \langle x,x_m \rangle |= |\langle x,x_n-x_m \rangle|\leq\|x\|\|x_n-x_m\| $$

Then $x_n$ cauchy implies that  $\langle x,x_n \rangle $ cauchy( in $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$)

How above define a continuous linear functional $L(x)=\lim\limits_{n } \langle x,x_n \rangle $.

By hypothesis there is a $z\in X$ such that $L(x)=\langle x,z \rangle $. Even we know in advance that X is Hilbert then we will conclude only that $x_n$ converge to $z$ weakly.

This is not a answer of course. Is a comment that does not fit in the place of comment.

@RobertIsrael,@ccc Can you give another hint?

Comment: Weak convergence + Cauchy implies convergence.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but since none of the answeres are complete I am giving a complete solution.  Let $x_{n}$ be a Cauchy sequence

First notice that $\langle y,x_{n}\rangle$ will always be a Cauchy sequence in $\Bbb{K}$ for each $y\in H$  as $|\langle y,x_{n}\rangle-\langle y,x_{m}\rangle|\leq ||y||\cdot||x_{n}-x_{m}||$ .

Thus $\lim_{n\to\infty} \langle y,x_{n}\rangle$ always exists.

As per Robert's answer define for each $y\in H$ , $L(y)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\langle y,x_{n}\rangle$ . Then $L$ is a linear functional and it is also bounded due to Cauchy-Schwartz inequality as $||x_{n}||$ is a bounded sequence.

Thus $L(\cdot)=\langle \cdot,z\rangle$ for some $z\in H$ by hypothesis.

Now let $\epsilon>0$ and $N$ be such that $||x_{n}-x_{m}||<\epsilon$ for all $n,m\geq N$

Then for a fixed $n\geq N$ consider the continuous functional $T(y)=\langle y,\frac{x_{n}-z}{||x_{n}-z||}\rangle$ . Then $||T||=1$ and $||T(x_{n}-z)||=||x_{n}-z||$ . Then notice that as $\langle y,x_{m}\rangle \to \langle y,z\rangle$ for each $y$ , we have $\displaystyle\lim_{m\to\infty}\langle \frac{x_{n}-z}{||x_{n}-z||}, x_{m}\rangle= \langle \frac{x_{n}-z}{||x_{n}-z||}, z\rangle $ which also means that $\displaystyle\lim_{m\to\infty}\langle x_{m},\frac{x_{n}-z}{||x_{n}-z||} \rangle= \langle z,\frac{x_{n}-z}{||x_{n}-z||}\rangle $

(Notice that we are taking limit wrt $m$ and not $n$ )

Then for $m\geq n\geq N$ we have

$\begin{align}||x_{n}-z||=||T(x_{n}-z)||&=||T(x_{n}-x_{m})+T(x_{m}-z)||\\
&\leq ||T||\cdot||x_{n}-x_{m}||+\bigg\vert\langle x_{m},\frac{x_{n}-z}{||x_{n}-z||}\rangle-\langle z,\frac{x_{n}-z}{||x_{n}-z||}\rangle\bigg\vert\\ &\leq \epsilon + \bigg\vert\langle x_{m},\frac{x_{n}-z}{||x_{n}-z||}\rangle-\langle z,\frac{x_{n}-z}{||x_{n}-z||}\rangle\bigg\vert \end{align}$

Now we can let $m\to\infty$ so that the term above is also $<\epsilon$ .

So $||x_{n}-z||\leq 2\epsilon$ for all $n\geq N$ .

Note that what Robert's answer does is show that $x_{n}\xrightarrow{w} z$ . What we have done is show that Cauchy+weak convergence in a normed space is equivalent to Convergence.  Now essentially we are producing  functionals $f_{n}$ of operator norm $1$ such that $|f_{n}(x_{n}-z)|=||x_{n}-z||$. In a more general space(not necessarily complete) , you'll need Hahn Banach Theorem to do so. Now we are using the Cauchyness of $x_{n}$ and the fact that $f_{n}(x_{m})\xrightarrow{m\to\infty} f_{n}(z)$ to conclude that $x_{n}\to z$ .