# $AB-BA$ is a nilpotent matrix if it commutes with $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I saw this in a [MathOverflow post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/15050) and am putting it here for posterity.

**Problem:**
Let $A$ and $B$ by square matrices and set $C=AB-BA$. If $AC=CA$, prove $C$ is nilpotent.

Comment: This is one of the facts known as Jacobson's lemma. See, e.g., [Janko Bracic, *On the Jacobson's lemma*](https://jankobracic.files.wordpress.com/2011/02/on-the-jacobsons-lemma.pdf) or [Irving Kaplansky, *Jacobson's lemma revisited*](https://doi.org/10.1016/0021-8693(80)90196-9). Note that $A$ and $B$ need to be matrices over a field of characteristic $0$ for this to hold. Otherwise, this would fail for the $2\times 2$-matrices $A = E_{1,2}$ and $B = E_{2,1}$ over the field $\mathbb{F}_2$ (where $E_{i,j}$ denotes the $2\times 2$-matrix with a $1$ in cell $\left(i, j\right)$ and $0$ elsewhere).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I use this theorem:

> If $\forall i\ge1$, $\mathrm{tr}(C^i)=0$, then $C$ is nilpotent.

You can easily prove by  induction that $\mathrm{tr}(C^i)=0$ for all $i\ge1$.

Theorem. $\forall i\ge1$, $\mathrm{tr}(C^i)=0$ iff $C$ is nilpotent.

Proof: $C$ is a real matrix but you may assume $C$ is a complex matrix and $$f(x)=(x-a_1)(x-a_2)\cdots(x-a_n)$$ is its characteristic polynomial in the complex field. You can prove that $\mathrm{tr}(C^k)=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^k$ by induction, and if  $\forall k\in\mathbb N$, $\mathrm{tr}(C^k)=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^k=0$  then $a_i=0$. Hence, $f(x)=x^n$, so $C^n=0$ and it is shown that $C$ is nilpotent.

Comment: Could you please use sentences with punctuation?  It looks like a good approach, but I have a little trouble parsing what is meant.

Comment: @jonas-meyer:induction that use in body proof  is so  prolix  sorry i don't write it

Comment: But you can at least separate this into a couple of paragraphs and so on. Readability goes a long way into turning something into a useful and enjoyable piece of text.

Comment: @Maisam: You can separate into paragraphs using blank lines between them.  Within a paragraph, you can separate ideas into sentences, by placing a period (dot) at the end of each sentence, and capitalizing the first letter of the subsequent sentence.  (This has to do with communication rather than mathematics per se.)

Answer (score 4):

Suppose $\mathcal A$ is a normed algebra and $\delta:\mathcal A\to\mathcal A$ is a bounded derivation.  If $x\in A$ and $\delta(\delta(x))=0$, then $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\|\delta(x)^n\|^{1/n}=0$.  This is proved as [Theorem 2.2.1](http://books.google.com/books?id=fgYPJyqBBwUC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA18#v=onepage&q&f=false) in [Sakai's *Operator algebras in dynamical systems*](http://books.google.com/books/about/Operator_Algebras_in_Dynamical_Systems.html?id=fgYPJyqBBwUC).

This applies to the case where $\mathcal A=M_n(\mathbb C)$, $\delta(X)= AX-XA$.  For an $n$-by-$n$ real or complex matrix $C$, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\|C^n\|^{1/n}=0$ if and only if $C$ is nilpotent.

(I also remarked on this application in an answer to a [different question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54397/the-identity-cannot-be-a-commutator-in-a-banach-algebra) where the result was applicable.)