# $A,B \in M_2(\mathbb C)$ be such that $AB-BA=B^2$ ; then is it true that $AB=BA$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $A,B \in M_2(\mathbb C)$ be such that $AB-BA=B^2$. Then is it true that $AB=BA$ ?

If we can show $\mathrm{tr}(B)=\det (B)=0$, then we are done by using $B^2-(\mathrm{tr}(B)) B+\det (B)=0$; but I don't know how to show even that.  Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know if it helps, but, $(A-B)(A+B)=A^2-BA+AB-B^2=A^2+B^2-B^2=A^2$.

Comment: @MichaelBurr : That off-course is true

Comment: uhm, if $AB=BA$ then $AB-BA = 0$.

Comment: @Thomas So I guess you could say the problem is to show whether $B^2 = 0$. It doesn't really matter.

Comment: @Thomas , Arthur : Yeah that's true

Comment: @Arthur well, yes. But that's a rather complicated way of stating this.

Comment: @Arthur But given condition only say that trace($B^2$)=0?

Comment: @Thomas It's rather common problem type to give some condition on two matrices and then ask whether they commute. Asking whether $B^2 = 0$ would seem off in that context.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We prove the following generalized claim:

> **Claim.** Assume that $AB - BA = B^p$ for some $p \geq 2$. Then $AB = BA$.

This is equivalent to proving that $B^p = 0$. To this end, we notice that

1. $\operatorname{tr}(B^p) = \operatorname{tr}(AB - BA) = 0$ since $\operatorname{tr}(AB) = \operatorname{tr}(BA)$.
2. We have $\det(B^p) = 0$. Indeed, if $\det(B^p) \neq 0$, then $B$ is invertible. Multiplying $B^{-p}$ to the left, we have
   $$B^{-p}AB - B^{1-p}A = I_2.$$
   But this is impossible since
   $$2 = \operatorname{tr}(I_2) \neq \operatorname{tr}((B^{-p}A)B - B(B^{-p}A)) = 0.$$

Applying Cayley-Hamilton theorem, we find that $B$ is nilpotent:

$$B^{2p} = \operatorname{tr}(B^p)I - \det(B^p)I_2 = 0.$$

Therefore we must have $B^2 = 0$ and hence $B^p = 0$. ////

---

**Addendum: Counter-example for $p = 1$.** For any $a_1, a_2, b \in \Bbb{C}$ with $b \neq 0$, put

$$ A = \begin{pmatrix} a_1 & a_2 \\ 0 & a_1 - 1 \end{pmatrix}, \qquad B = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & b \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}. \tag{*} $$

Then $AB - BA = B$.

Conversely, if $A, B \in M_2(\Bbb{C})$ is such that $AB - BA = B$ and $B \neq 0$, then $A$ and $B$ can be written as $\text{(*)}$ up to *unitary change of basis*.

(*Remark.* Using the Jordan normal form, it is straightforward that this is true up to change of basis.)

Indeed, since $\det(B) = 0$, $B$ has rank 1 and we may write

$$ B = b \begin{pmatrix} u_1 \bar{v}_1 & u_1 \bar{v}_2 \\ u_2 \bar{v}_1 & u_2 \bar{v}_2 \end{pmatrix} $$

for some $b \neq 0$ and for some unit vectors $u = (u_1, u_2), v = (v_1, v_2)$. Then $\operatorname{tr}(B) = 0$ is equivalent to $\langle u, v \rangle = 0$ and hence $u, v$ are orthogonal. In particular, $B$ corresponds to the linear map

$$ Bx = b\langle v, x \rangle u. $$

(Here, the 2nd argument of the Hermitian inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ is chosen to be linear.) Then the claim follows by rewriting everything w.r.t. the orthonormal basis $\{u, v\}$ and solving the equation $AB - BA = B$.

Comment: Dear @Sangchul,Nice Solution.Bravo!

Comment: @ArpitKansal, Thank you!

Comment: @SangchulLee : From $B^4=O$ , we don't actually even need any minimal polynomial or so ; just that then $B$ is nilpotent and $B$ is $2 \times 2$ matrix ! so $B^2=O$

Comment: @user228169, But isn't it essential to consider minimal polynomial when proving that fact? I may be wrong, but it seems to me that some non-trivial observation is required to push the exponent $m$ of $A^m = 0$ all the way down to the ambient dimension.

Comment: @SangchulLee : No no , not necessarily essential ; if say $k$ be the degree of nilpotency , then there is a non-zero vector $v$ such that $A^{k-1}v \ne 0$ and then you can show that $\{v,Av,...,A^{k-1}v \}$ is linearly independent ; hence $ k \le n$

Comment: @user228169, Oh, that makes sense. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Sangchul Lee : no , no ; Thank you :)

Answer (score 6):

It is easy to show that a matrix $B\in M_n(K)$ satisfying, for some $p\ge 1$
$$
AB-BA=B^p
$$
is nilpotent and hence satisfies $B^n=0$, see Proposition $2.2$ [here](https://homepage.univie.ac.at/Dietrich.Burde/papers/burde_20_matrix_equ.pdf). The proof uses the Vandermonde determinant. In your case we obtain that $B$ is a nilpotent matrix of size $2$, so that $B^2=0$, and hence $AB=BA$.

More generally, $AB-BA$ is nilpotent, if it commutes with $A$ (or $B$), see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/299640/ab-ba-is-a-nilpotent-matrix-if-it-commutes-with-a).

Comment: Dear @Dietrich,Don't you need to assume $p >1$ ?

Comment: Oh, in your proof of Prop 2.2 you jumped twice to get that trace $0$,, with no warning  :-)

Comment: Dear @ArpitKansal: No, it is also true for $p=1$. This has been discussed on MSE very often i see, e.g., [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/724294/if-a-ab-ba-then-an-0), or [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/811160/ab-ba-a-implies-a-is-singular-and-a-is-nilpotent). Also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/724294/if-a-ab-ba-then-an-0)., or [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1440740/proof-for-a-b-in-m-n-mathbbf-that-if-a-b-ta-for-0-neq-t-in-mathbbf?lq=1).

Comment: Dear @DietrichBurde I see.Thank you.Regards,

Comment: Dear @ArpitKansal I should be more precise. For $p=1$ it is still true that $B$ is nilpotent. The counterexample above states that $AB=BA$ need not be true then.

Comment: Dear @DietrichBurde I see your point.Thank you,again!

Answer (score 0):

We have $B^3= BAB-AB^2=AB^2-BAB$, hence $AB^2=B^2A$.

Hence $A$ commute with $B^2$, but we know that $B^2= tr(B)B-det(B)Id$
Therefore, if $tr(B)\not =0$, $A$ commmute with $B$.

If $tr (B)=0$,   $B^2=det(B) Id$. 
If $det(B) =0, B^2=0$ and we are done.

If not the two eigenvalues of $B$ are opposite (tr=0) and non zero,  then $tr(B^2)=\lambda^2\not =0$, contradiction as $tr B^2=tr(AB-BA)=0$

Comment: Actually $B^3=BAB-B^2A=AB^2-BAB$, and it hard to see how this leads to $AB^2=B^2A$. A wrong answer in my opinion. (-1)