# $AB − BA = A$, $A$ is a nonzero matrix then $B$ is not nilpotent.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Let $A,B$ $n\times n$ matrices such that $$AB-BA=A$$ and $A$ is a nonzero matrix. Prove that $B$ is not nilpotent.

I know why $A$ is nilpotent, but how can I prove $B$ is **not** nilpotent?

Comment: Why **is** $A$ nilpotent?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Because of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/811160/ab-ba-a-implies-a-is-singular-and-a-is-nilpotent).

Answer (score 8):

Here's one way to see it: define the linear transformation
$$
\Phi_B(X) = XB - BX
$$
clearly, $A$ is an eigenvector of this transformation associated with $\lambda = 1$.  Now, the eigenvalues of $\Phi_B$ are necessarily of the form $\lambda - \mu$ where $\lambda,\mu$ are eigenvalues of $B$ (can be seen via [vectorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics))).

Conclude that since $\Phi_B$ has a non-zero eigenvalue, $B$ has a non-zero eigenvalue, which means it is not nilpotent.

Comment: Also, excellent!

Comment: why is the eigenvectors of Φ_B such form?

Comment: Find the eigenvectors of $X\mapsto XB$ and $X\mapsto BX$, then note that the two operators commute.

Answer (score 6):

If $B$ is nilpotent then there is $k$ such that $AB^k=0$.

So $-BAB^{k-1}=AB^k-BAB^{k-1}=(AB-BA)B^{k-1}=AB^{k-1}$.

Hence, $(Id+B)(AB^{k-1})=0$. Since B is nilpotent then $Id+B$ is invertible. Thus, $AB^{k-1}=0$.

We can repeat the argument to prove that $AB^{k-2}=\ldots=AB^1=AB^0=A=0$. Absurd!