# Let $A, B, C$ be some complex matrices. If $AB - BA = C$ and $AC = CA$, then $C^k = 0$ for some $k$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form

> Let $A, B, C$ be some complex matrices. Suppose that $AB - BA = C$ and $AC = CA$. Prove that: $C^k = 0$ for some $k$.

It is an exercise in the section of "Jordan Canonical Form of Nilpotent Transforms". But I am not sure how to prove the question. Could anyone give me a hint?

Comment: One can infer this, but I think it should be explicitly stated that these matrices are square.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$C=AB-BA$ is a nilpotent matrix if it commutes with $A$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/299640/ab-ba-is-a-nilpotent-matrix-if-it-commutes-with-a)

Comment: The idea is to prove that the trace of $C$ is zero. If this is true, then it is similar to a Jordan form matrix with trace 0, which is nilpotent of degree $n$ (where $n$ is the size of the matrix).