# How to show that there do not exist bounded operators $A$ and $B$ such that $AB-BA=I$

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose $X$ is a Banach space, $A$ and $B$  are bounded operators on $X$. Then how to show that it's impossible to have 
$$AB-BA=I$$
If $A$  and $B$ are matrix, then we just take trace of both side to obtain contradiction,since  $trAB=trBA$. Furthermore, this can only hold for bounded operators since if allow  $A$  and $B$ to be unbounded, we have $[\frac{d}{dx},x]=I$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a proof at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54397/the-identity-cannot-be-a-commutator-in-a-banach-algebra

Comment: thanks very much, I didn't notice that before.