# Checking of continuity of the operators

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, continuity, operator-theory

Let $X$ be a normed vector space and $S,T : X → X$ be linear and such that $ST −TS = Id$. Show that either $S$ or $T$ is not continuous.

Comment: Check out the answer by Geoff Robinson in [this MSE question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54397/the-identity-cannot-be-a-commutator-in-a-banach-algebra/54399#54399). It shows that the identity cannot be a commutator of two bounded operators, so if it is a commutator, one of the operators must be unbounded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me give an answer that also works if $\mathcal L(X)$ is not a Banach algebra, i.e. if $X$ is real or noncomplete.

We show by induction that $ST^{n+1}-T^{n+1}S = (n+1)T^n$:

The base case is clear. Now if this is true for some $n\in \mathbb N$, then

\begin{align}
&ST^{n+1}-T^{n+1}S = (n+1)T^n \\\
\Rightarrow\quad &ST^{n+2}-T^{n+1}ST = (n+1)T^{n+1} \\\
\Rightarrow\quad &ST^{n+2}-T^{n+1}(ST-Id)-T^{n+1} = (n+1)T^{n+1}\\\
\Rightarrow\quad &ST^{n+2}-T^{n+1}(TS) = (n+2)T^{n+1} \\\
\Rightarrow\quad &ST^{n+2}-T^{n+2}S = (n+2)T^{n+1}.
\end{align}

Inductively it follows aswell that $T^n\neq 0$ for each $n\in\mathbb N$.

But now $(n+1)\|T^n\| \leq 2\|S\|\|T^{n+1}\|\leq 2\|S\|\|T\|\|T^n\|$. Dividing by $\|T^n\|$ (assuming it is finite) yields $$(n+1)\leq 2\|S\|\|T\|$$ for each $n\in\mathbb N$, hence one of $S,T$ must be unbounded.

Comment: very nice answer.Thanks