# Given two non-commuting linear operators prove that at least one is discontinuous

Tags: functional-analysis

Given a normed space $X \neq \{0\}$ and $P, Q : X \rightarrow X$ linear such that $$PQ - QP = \mathbb{1}_X$$ Prove that at least one of P and Q is discontinuous.

Hint: Prove and use that $PQ^n - Q^nP = nQ^{n-1}$.

I was able to prove the hint, but I'm not able to use it. My idea was to try to prove this by contradiction, assume that both P and Q are bounded, then try to calculate the norm of Q by using the hint and recursively replacing the $Q^n$s in hopes of coming up with some non-converging series using the 'n terms', but this only leads to a mess. Can someone give some help please?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/54413/588038

Comment: Thanks. Why does the last inequality hold? $\|xy^{n} -y^{n}x\| \leq 2\|x\|. \|y\| .
\|y^{n-1} \|$

Comment: Use the triangle inequality.

Comment: yes, but I dont see how you can apply it here

Comment: $\|xy^{n} -y^{n}x\| \leq \|xy^{n}\| +\|y^{n}x\|  \leq \|x\| \cdot\|y\| \cdot \|y^{n-1} \| +  \|x\|  \cdot\|y\|  \cdot\|y^{n-1} \| =2\|x\| \cdot\|y\|  \cdot\|y^{n-1} \|$. Recall that the operator norm is submultiplicative.

Comment: Yes it did, thanks for the help.